# Rails update_attributes not working for Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails project I am using Postgresql.

```
User.find_by_sql("update users set address = '#{params[:address]}' where id = #{current_user.id}")
```

This code is working fine, but the equivalent activerecord is not working :

```
   user = User.find(current_user.id)
   user.update_attributes(:address => params[:address])
```

it always shows `Begin; Rollback` in log.
Can you please explain why is this happening? Is there any issue related to Postgres?
I am using Rails 3.2

**EDIT**

I found out where i was wrong... a validation fail was causing this.
The solution is :

```
  user.update_column(:address,params[:address])
```

This will bypass validation.
Thank you guys for help.

Comment: can you show your User model please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001862) updates the record if all the validations pass, so one of your validation must have failed, use `user.errors` to find out the errors:

```
user = User.find(current_user.id)
user.update_attributes(:address => params[:address])
puts user.errors
```

In order to save a single column, use [`update_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001861).

```
user.update_attribute(:address, params[:address])
```

Comment: Thanks, my validation failed....
is there any way I can skip the validation ?? .
because i just need to save 1 column without validation.

Comment: try `user.update_attribute(:address, params[:address])` OR `User.update_all("address = #{params[:address]}", "id = #{user.id}")`

Comment: You can do `user.address = params[:address]`  and then `user.save(:validate => false)` to skip the validations

Comment: @AmitThawait:- I Agree Amit

Comment: `user.errors.full_messages` would be more useful since, `user.errors` would only return an `ActiveModel::Errors` instance and not the error messages. :)

Comment: user.errors saved my bacon. user.update(...), user.update_attributes(...) and user.something = something_else; user.save...all returned nothing in the way of debugging why my update was failing.

Answer (score 3):

check for failures:

```
user.update_attributes!(...)
```

Comment: This is useful to output on the console why the update failed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `attr_accessible` in your model but not including :address, update_attributes will appear to work but the record won't save.